# NGINX proxy to a Zeit Now deployment

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, vercel

I have several application server running several Node applications (via PM2).

I have one NGINX server which has the SSL certificate for the domain and reverse-proxies to the Node applications.

Within the NGINX configuration file I set the domains with their location block like this:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name
          geolytix.xyz;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/geolytix.xyz/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/geolytix.xyz/privkey.pem;

        location /demo {
            proxy_pass http://159.65.61.61:3000/demo;
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }

        location /now {
            proxy_pass https://xyz-heigvbokgr.now.sh/now;
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }
}
```

This only works for the application server. The proxy to the Zeit Now deployment yields a bad gateway. The application itself work as expected if I go to the Zeit Now address of my deployment.

Does anybody know whether I might be missing some settings to proxy to Zeit Now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

now servers require the use of SNI for https connections. Like almost all modern webservers.
You need do add

```
proxy_ssl_server_name    on;
```

to your configuration.

The smallest location block would be the following:

```
location / {
     proxy_set_header        host my-app.now.sh;
     proxy_ssl_server_name   on;
     proxy_pass              https://alias.zeit.co;
}
```